Langchain - APIChain, Getting error as "is not in the allowed domains"
Below my code, its simple API interaction
  chain=APIChain.from_llm_and_api_docs(
        llm,
        api_docs,
        verbose=True,
        limit_to_domains=["https://api.coincap.io"]
    )
    response=chain.invoke("what is the price of ethereum")
    print(response)

getting this error,
Note that we are not including any additional query parameters or making any modifications to the endpoint, as the basic endpoint provides us with the necessary information to answer the user's question. is not in the allowed domains: ['https://api.coincap.io']
